# How to fix this npm error trying to update

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

```
leolemus@Leos-MBP-2 ~ % npm install -g npm@latest
npm does not support Node.js v15.11.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@8.3.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@8.3.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.3.0","node":"v15.11.0"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/leolemus/.npm/_logs/2021-12-12T02_35_45_442Z-debug-0.log
```

I use macos 11.2.2 And I have node installed via homebrew. It says it's up to date when I do "brew upgrade node".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check which version you're using with:

```
node --version
```

If you're not using the Node you installed you can unlink the version you don't want with

```
brew unlink node
```

Install the node version you want:

```
brew install node@version
```

Then link to it with:

```
brew link node@version
```

Validate you're using it with:

```
node --version
```